# Open loop gain of op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, loop-gain

[image]

I am not sure I am analyzing this correctly, but here's an attempt:
\$20lgA_o=92.0412dB\$, yielding \$A_o=40K\$

And

\$20lgA_o-20lg(1+100K/\omega_b)=40\$, yielding \$f_b=40.08Hz\$, hence \$f_t=f_bA_o=1.6032MHz\$

Are these values correct?

Comment: Try use this $$A = \frac{Ao}{\sqrt{1+\left( \frac{F}{F_B} \right)^2}}$$

Comment: I get Fb = 250Hz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are these values correct?

I don't think you are correct for fb. Consider this: -

- at 100 kHz the gain is 40 dB therefore
- at 10 kHz the gain is 60 dB
- at 1 kHz the gain is 80 dB

If this kept rising as frequency dropped you'd get 100 dB at 100 Hz so clearly this cannot happen and somewhere between 100 Hz and 1 kHz you'd get 92 dB - I estimate about 200 Hz off the top of my head.

For ft just go up by a factor of 100 in frequency from 100 kHz and you get 10 MHz and two lots of reduction by 20 dB therefore, 0 dB gain is at 10 MHz.